# Array of objects filter by another array values

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new in Angular and trying to use as a filter values of array, that is inside object, which is inside another array.
Second file, that should be filtered, contains array of objects.
for example:

```
export const PART: Parts [] = [
  {
    title: 'param1',
    data: 'some data', //required information to get
  },
  {
    title: 'param2',
    data: 'other data',
  },
  {
    title: 'param3',
    data: 'another data',
  }
]



export const PROD: Prod[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'item1',
    title: ['param1', 'param3']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'item2',
    title: ['param2', 'param3']
  }
]
```

expected result:
item1 receive in it's description data: 'some data' and 'another data'.
item2 receive in it's description data: 'other data' and 'another data'.
I would use method *ngFor in template for both items.

I need to assign data from const PART to item of const PROD according title 'param1'.
Unfortunately I can't find any code example, that would work in this scenario.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the expected output, given the two arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prod.map((x)=>{
    x.title.map((y)=>{
        part.map((z)=>{
            if(y == z.title && x.id == 1){
                x.data.push(z.data)
            }
            if(y == z.title && x.id == 2){
                x.data.push(z.data)
            }
        })
    })
})
change prod to this add data:[]
[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'item1',
      title: ['param1', 'param3'],
      data:[]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'item2',
      title: ['param2', 'param3'],
      data:[]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Although i don't understand why is needed second "if", because code is working without it and without second parameter "&& x.id == 1".

Answer (score 0):

Modify the PROD type as below.

```
export interface PROD {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  title: string[] | Array<string>;
  data: Array<string>;
}
```

You can modify the PROD array to accommodate data object as below.

```
export const PROD: Prod[] = [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'item1',
  title: ['param1', 'param3'],
  data: [],
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: 'item2',
  title: ['param2', 'param3'],
  data: [],
 },
];
```

Use the below functions to assign data to the PROD array based on the param in the title. Loop through the array in onInit or your respective function to assign the data.

```
findPartWithParams(param: string): any {
 return this.PART.find((e: PART) => e.title === param);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.PROD.forEach((prod: Prod) => {
    prod.title.forEach((t: string) => {
      prod.data.push(this.findPartWithParams(t).data);
    });
  });
}
```

I have attached a working StackBlitz fork for reference.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-12bkcd

Comment: i did tried that example, but received error on "findPartWithParams(param)" "Parameter 'param' implicitly has an 'any' type."  and on "(this.findPartWithParams(t).data);" error "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'".

Comment: correction, sample is working in stackblitz, but i can not make it work in separate project. I have checked dependencies and they are all the same.

Comment: Can you share a stackblitz link of possible? A small replica of your code.

Comment: As i wrote previously - code is working fine in stackblitz, but in new created project it's not. Although code is identical in both cases. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xsnrja?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: The 1st comment you mentioned about a type error. Can you check for typecasting of the variables. I have modified the answer to accommodate typecast of parameters. Also the stackblitz code is updated with typecast.

Comment: I have added your suggested changes to the project and it solved issue with "param any", but now appeared new one: line "return this.PART.find((e) => e.title === param)" gives error "Type 'PART | undefined' is not assignable to type 'PART'"

Comment: You can replace the return type with any. As mentioned above